# Alterar option de um select via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Preciso desenvolver uma função.
Tem um menu com alguns links.

Ao clica em um link preciso que as opções os `<option>` de um `<select>` altere.

Os dados desse `<select>` esta vindo direto do banco. Preciso criar grupos  no *javascript* que ao click no `link B` venha o `grupo B`, se clica no `link T` só o `grupo T`.

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Sua resposta está aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64386/trocar-de-tipo-de-campo-de-formul%C3%A1rio-com-onclick

Comment: Você poderia talvez usar o Select2 um componente que separa o Dropbox em grupos olha em https://select2.github.io/